# Search in JSONB column with unstructured data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column in my table which stores unstructured data in my PostgreSQL database. I need to search for a specific key value pair, but I do not know where that key value is exactly.
For example if I am searching for

```
“name”: “John”
```

the data could look like this:

```
{       “id”: 1,
        “name”: “John”
        “cars”: []
}
```

However, in another row that key value pair may appear inside an array, or another object (not on the first level)

```
{
    “id”: 1, 
        “students”: 
            [
                {
                    “id”: 2,
                    “name”: “John”
                 }
            ]
}
```

Is there any way that I can search for a specific key value pair without knowing where it is?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  version 9.6.14

Comment: Then this is going to be very hard. In Postgres 12, you could do `where the_column @? '$.** ? (@.name == "John")'`

Comment: is there any way I can do this in version 9.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of in 9.6 is to create a function that recursively goes through all elements and returns a "flattened" view on the JSON value.

```
create or replace function flatten(p_input jsonb)
  returns table(key text, value text)
as
$$
begin
  if jsonb_typeof(p_input) = 'array' then 
    return query 
      select f.*
      from jsonb_array_elements(p_input) as a(element)
        cross join flatten(a.element) f;
  else
    return query
      select e.key, e.value #>> '{}'
      from jsonb_each(p_input) as e(key, value)
      where jsonb_typeof(e.value) not in ('object', 'array')
  
      union all
    
      select f.*
      from jsonb_each(p_input) as t(key,value)
        cross join flatten(t.value) as f
      where jsonb_typeof(t.value) = 'object'

      union all
  
      select f.*
      from jsonb_each(p_input) as t(key,value)
        cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.value) as a(element)
        cross join flatten(a.element) as f
      where jsonb_typeof(t.value) = 'array';
  end if;
end;  
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
select t.*
from the_table 
where exists (select * 
              from flatten(t.the_column) 
              where t.key = 'name' 
                and t.value = 'John');
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e4a9ccab096ddf14bb8fcdbc46bc54a8)